# Spark SQL - Join that produces an array of matches instead of one row per match

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working in Spark SQL (specifically in Java), and am having an issue when joining, when the join conditions have multiple matches.

I am receiving a row in my output for each of the matches, but I would like instead for these to be folded together into one array of values matching the join condition.

Let's say I have the following two tables:

**locations**

```
location  | animal1 | animal2 | animal3
---------------------------------------
australia | badger  | duck    | penguin
thailand  | moose   | penguin | horse
brazil    | zebra   | cow     | pigeon
mexico    | rhino   | donkey  | cat
```

**bannedAnimals**

```
banned_animal | banned_animal_ID
--------------------------------
penguin       | 1
zebra         | 2
moose         | 3
```

What I want to do, is assemble a table containing locations, and then a column containing the IDs of all animals banned there. For example, the two tables above would produce:

```
location  | banned_animal_IDs
--------------------------------
australia | [1]
thailand  | [1,3]
brazil    | [2]
```

I do not care about the ordering of the IDs in the array, if there are multiple, so for the `Thailand` entry I am equally happy with `[1,3]` and `[3,1]`

What I am getting now, which is *not* what I'm looking for, is:

```
location  | banned_animal_IDs
--------------------------------
australia | 1
thailand  | 1
thailand  | 3
brazil    | 2
```

The way I'm doing this:

```
Dataset<Row> bannedAnimalsByLocation = locations
                .join(bannedAdminals, joinColumn, "INNER");
```

where the `joinColumn` is the banned_animal column

There may be lots of other columns in the `locations` table, so I can't just do a `.groupBy` on the `location` column.

Comment: If you don't want to lose the other columns, try using a window function with `collect_set` as aggregation function. Then take the row with the most entries and filter all other rows.

Comment: how can `banned_animal` be the join column, it does not appear in `locations` dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val locations = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("australia", "badger", "duck", "penguin"),
    ("thailand", "moosen", "penguin", "horse"),
    ("brazil", "zebra", "cow", "pigeon"),
    ("mexico", "rhino", "donkey", "cat")
    )).toDF("location","animal1", "animal2", "animal3")


val bannedAdminals = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("penguin", "1"),
    ("zebra", "2"),
    ("moosen", "3")
    )).toDF("banned_animal", "banned_animal_ID")



val dfJoined = locations.join(bannedAdminals, locations("animal1") === bannedAdminals("banned_animal")
                                            or locations("animal2") === bannedAdminals("banned_animal")
                                            or locations("animal3") === bannedAdminals("banned_animal"))
                        .select("location", "banned_animal_ID")

dfJoined.groupBy("location").agg(collect_set("banned_animal_ID")).show
```

The result :

```
+---------+-----------------------------+
| location|collect_set(banned_animal_ID)|
+---------+-----------------------------+
|australia|                          [1]|
| thailand|                       [3, 1]|
|   brazil|                          [2]|
+---------+-----------------------------+
```